# How to Hide and Table Show using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, html-table

I want to click in character "-" the  would be hiding and turn to "+" and when I click "+" < id="noidung"> would be show and turn to "-".
Here is my code in View :

```
<tr style="">
      <td style="width:50%; background-color:#b4abab; height:20px">
       <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><b id="hide" style="font-size:20px">-</b><b hidden id="show" style="font-size:20px">+</b></a>
       <input style="margin-left:10px" id="ChkControllers" type="checkbox" name="ccc" value="@item.ID" />@item.Control
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<tr style="width:50%">

 <td id="noidung">
    @foreach (var lstAction in listAction)
             {

                if (ViewBag.SelectedRole != null)
                   {

                       <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" @Tolerance.ModelsAdmin.Utinity.GetActionByRoleControllers((int)@item.ID, ViewBag.SelectedRole, lstAction.ID) type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

**And this is my js code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("#noidung").hide();
        $("#hide").hide();
        $("#show").show();
    });
    $("#show").click(function () {

        $("#hide").show();
        $("#show").hide();
        $("#noidung").show();
    });

});
```

......

I want to know why I just can hide and show in the 1st row?
 How can I do it with another rows?

Comment: Because you have invalid html. `id` attributes must be unique and you code `$("#noidung").hide();` and `$("#noidung").show();` will only ever select the first element with `id="noidung"`. You need to use class names instead

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you to hide and display the row content when you press -, + button respectively .

So if each row is having these buttons we will try to find out the nearest sibling with class 'noidung' . So what we can apply our logic. So instead of seperating it in two rows I have merged it in to one row

So as we will be having -,+ button for each row . We will remove the id and make it as class as below

```
<tr style="">
      <td style="width:50%; background-color:#b4abab; height:20px">
       <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><b class="hide" style="font-size:20px">-</b><b hidden class="show" style="font-size:20px">+</b></a>
       <input style="margin-left:10px" id="ChkControllers" type="checkbox" name="ccc" value="@item.ID" />@item.Control
                        </td>

 <td class="noidung">
    @foreach (var lstAction in listAction)
             {

                if (ViewBag.SelectedRole != null)
                   {

                       <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" @Tolerance.ModelsAdmin.Utinity.GetActionByRoleControllers((int)@item.ID, ViewBag.SelectedRole, lstAction.ID) type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Now we will the add the event for + , - button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".hide").click(function () {
       $('.hide', $(this).closest(".noidung")).hide();
        $(".hide").hide();
        $(".show").show();
    });
    $(".show").click(function () {

        $('.show', $(this).closest(".noidung")).show();
        $(".show").hide();
        $(".hide").show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Run Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qpumymjp/32/)

Try,

> Replace

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><b class="hide" style="font-size:20px">-</b><b hidden class="show" style="font-size:20px">+</b></a>
```

> with

```
 <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" class='displayShowHide'>-</a>
```

**your new html should be**

```
<tr style="">
      <td style="width:50%; background-color:#b4abab; height:20px">
       <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" class='displayShowHide'>-</a>
       <input style="margin-left:10px" id="ChkControllers" type="checkbox" name="ccc" value="@item.ID" />@item.Control
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<tr style="width:50%">

 <td id="noidung">
    @foreach (var lstAction in listAction)
             {

                if (ViewBag.SelectedRole != null)
                   {

                       <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" @Tolerance.ModelsAdmin.Utinity.GetActionByRoleControllers((int)@item.ID, ViewBag.SelectedRole, lstAction.ID) type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               <input style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:5px;" id="@lstAction.ID" type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="@lstAction.ID" />@lstAction.Action
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

**add this in your Script**

```
$(function () {
    $('.displayShowHide').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).text() == '-')
            $('a').text('+');
        else
          $('a').text('-');

    });
});
```